# denormalizing data and updating it in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

We are building a social network. There are many places where details of a user is stored. For example, friends of a user, the user who created a comment etc. I am de-normalizing the user data(name, imageurl).

Now the question is how to update the de-normalized data. One option is to do it in a background job, whenever the user updates his name/image.

Is it the right way to de-normalize?

Is it the right way to update the denormalized data, or there is something provided by mongodb natively?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a background job to me, but it depends on your volume of updates and queries.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB doesn't support relations, triggers, needed to watch related objects state so you can't automatically update you denormalized data ([DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) doesn't feet). You have to do it manually.